# ASP.NET Core MVC ActionLink

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am new to ASP.NET Core and building a Project in .NET Core MVC.

In my Admin Area I have a controller UserRolesController and Action CreateRole (Works Alright)

In the View, I added a Hyperlink to the CreateRole Action

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" asp-controller="UserRoles" asp-action="CreateRole">Create Role</a>
```

But after running the link shows as `https://localhost:44332/UserRoles/CreateRole instead of https://localhost:44332/Admin/UserRoles/CreateRole`

Again link the Area to my Homepage returns `https://localhost:44332/UserRoles?area=Admin`instead of `https://localhost:44332/Admin/UserRoles`

This is how my routes are configured

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
            "admin",
            "Admin",
            "Admin/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
            "client",
            "Client",
            "Client/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
            "investor",
            "investor",
            "Investor/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
```

What am I doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need add `asp-area` tag helper:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" asp-area="Products" asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="CreateRole">Create Role</a>
```

OR

```
   @Html.ActionLink("Admin/UserRoles/CreateRole", "CreateRole", "UserRoles",new { area = "Admin" })
```

Click [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-3.1,) For more information

Comment: Still got the same results. It shows as :https://localhost:44332/UserRoles/CreateRole?area=Admin

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. You should modify the order to make the Areas route first :

```
endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
"area",
"Admin",
"{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"


endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

It worked for me